# Python Orange 3 ensemble stacking

Tags: python-3.x, orange

I'm having problems with working with stacking models in python 3 Orange.

I'm not sure whether stacking is not yet implemented for this version of python
using this command:

```
Orange.ensemble.stacking.StackedClassificationLearner(learners)
```

But it says that it can't find the Orange.ensemble package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in doubting that stacking is already implemented in Orange 3 (because it isn't).